# Getting error while compiling DeaDBeefPlayer

Tags: compiling, deadbeef

The output from bash:

```
/bin/bash: /home/barrakudarain/Progs/Musical: No such file or directory
Makefile:442: recipe for target 'install-pkglibLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[2]: *** [install-pkglibLTLIBRARIES] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/barrakudarain/Progs/Musical Players/DeadbeefPlayer/plugins/mp3'
Makefile:607: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/barrakudarain/Progs/Musical Players/DeadbeefPlayer/plugins/mp3'
Makefile:769: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

My default procedure is:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Help!

Comment: It seems not to like the space in your directory name `Musical Players` - try changing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DeaDBeeF player is perhaps not the most straightforward to compile and install but perhaps try the following procedure which worked well enough on my Zesty setup and I am sure with some adjustment would work well enough on other versions of Ubuntu:

**Install Build Tools & Dependencies**

You will need some build tools as well as some development files to build some of the DeaDBeeF plugins. Run the following *single command* from a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall intltool yasm \
libjansson-dev libmpg123-dev libvorbis-dev libflac-dev libwavpack-dev \
libsamplerate0-dev libgtk-3-dev libcdio-dev libcddb2-dev libsndfile1-dev \
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libfaad-dev libimlib2-dev libzip-dev \
libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libasound2-dev
```

Then build DeaDBeeF itself:

**Build and Install DeaDBeeF:**

Use the following *single command* to download, compile and install DeaDBeeF:

```
mkdir $HOME/dead_beef_build && cd $HOME/dead_beef_build && \
wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition \
http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/deadbeef-0.7.2.tar.bz2/download && \
tar xvf deadbeef-0.7.2.tar.bz2 && \
cd deadbeef-0.7.2 && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/dead_beef_build" --backup=no --deldoc=yes \
                  --pkgname deadbeef --pkgversion "0.7.2" --fstrans=no \
                  --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default && \
sudo ldconfig
```

And then DeaDBeeF should be right to go :).

**Plugins:**

During compile time you should see a list of plugins flying past. In this build you will have the following available:

```
Plugin Summary:

    stdio: yes - Standard IO plugin
    gme: yes - chiptune music player based on GME
    nullout: yes - NULL output
    alsa: yes - ALSA output
    oss: yes - oss output plugin
    pulse: no - PulseAudio output plugin
    coreaudio: no - CoreAudio output plugin
    sid: yes - SID player based on libsidplay2
    ffap: yes - Monkey's audio (APE) decoder
    lastfm: no - last.fm scrobbler
    mp3: yes - mp3 plugin
        libmad: no - libmad backend for mp3 plugin
        libmpg123: yes - libmpg123 backend for mp3 plugin
    vorbis: yes - ogg vorbis player
    flac: yes - flac player
    wavpack: yes - wavpack player
    sndfile: yes - PCM (wav,aiff,etc) player based on libsndfile
    vtx: yes - vtx file player (ay8910/12 emulation)
    adplug: yes - adplug player (OPL2/OPL3 emulation)
    vfs_curl: no - http/ftp streaming support
    cdda: yes - cd audio player
    gtkui: no - GTK2 user interface
    gtkui3: yes - GTK3 user interface
    hotkeys: yes - Local and global hotkeys support
    ffmpeg: yes - ffmpeg codecs
    artwork: no - Cover art plugin
    supereq: yes - Equalizer based on Super EQ library by Naoki Shibata
    notify: yes - notification-daemon support plugin
    shellexec: yes - shell commands plugin
    shellexecui: yes - GTK user interface for setting up shellexec plugin
    musepack: yes - musepack player plugin
    wildmidi: yes - WildMidi player plugin
    tta: yes - TTA player plugin
    dca: yes - libdca (DTS Audio) player plugin
    aac: yes - AAC player (m4a, aac, mp4) based on FAAD2
    mms: yes - mms streaming support
    dsp_src: yes - High quality samplerate conversion using libsamplerate
    m3u: yes - M3U and PLS playlist support
    vfs_zip: yes - zip archive support
    converter: yes - plugin for converting files to any formats
    psf: yes - PSF format plugin, using AOSDK
    dumb: yes - DUMB module plugin, for MOD, S3M, etc
    shn: yes - SHN plugin based on xmms-shn
    mono2stereo: yes - mono2stereo DSP plugin
    alac: yes - ALAC plugin
    wma: yes - WMA plugin
    pltbrowser: yes - playlist browser gui plugin
    sc68: yes - sc68 Atari ST And Amiga player
```

But more can be added by tracking down the required `-dev` files, installing these and then recompiling DeaDBeeF.

**Obligatory Screenshot:**

Here is a screenshot of DeaDBeeF running on my Zesty setup, using the above instructions:

[image]

And hopefully these detailed instructions will get you on the way as well :).